# Invalidity of propositional formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> It may be a silly doubt but I am really confused about valid and
>   invalid terms.

From whatever I read, I concluded that:

Validity and invalidity apply only to arguments, not to propositional statements.
For a (simple)statement either it can be true or false.
For arguments- It is valid if all the premises are true, then the conclusion must be true.
Invalid when it is possible that all the premises are true and the conclusion is false.

For a propositional formula (compound propositions) - a tautology, contingency, contradiction, satisfiable, unsatisfiable, valid terms make sense.

> Now my confusion is:
>
> 1. Can we use the $Invalid$ term with a compound proposition (propositional formula)? If yes, Then what is the condition for its invalidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly makes sense to have terminology to distinguish *truth/falsity* of propositional statements from *validity/invalidity* of arguments that purport to be logical reasoning.  On the other hand it is very common for authors to use *valid* to describe a compound formula with assignments of truth and falsity to its atomic propositions when it results in the overall formula being true (resp. *invalid* when an assignment gives a false result).

Good authors will be careful in the use of terminology (and in the definitions), but informal usage will vary.  Ultimately if you want to use the terms *valid/invalid* for compound propositions, you should provide consistent definitions that alert readers or listeners to your meaning.

Comment: Thank you. So usually authors use $valid$ terminology when a compound formula is a tautology and $invalid$ terminology when the truth table of formula contains $at least$ one $false$ ?

Comment: I'd say careful authors use the term *tautology* when every truth-table assignment gives *true* and *satisfiable* when *some* truth-table assignment gives *true*.  Even though the idea of truth-table assignments is clear and simple, from a computational complexity point of view this gives a non-polynomial time algorithm.  However (for Boolean logic) the respective problems of deciding **TAUT** and **SAT** are convertible in polynomial time.  I point this out mainly to motivate you to be articulate about your own definitions when using the term **valid** to refer to a compound formula.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s first clear a terminological point.

Validity as in “this argument is valid” belongs to classic formal logic.

Validity as in “a tautology is a valid proposition” belongs to model theory.

That’s two meaning of valid. In mathematical logic we can talk about a valid proposition (in the 2nd sense of “valid”). Roughly it means true under any possible interpretation. A contradiction is the negation of a valid proposition. A contingent proposition is a neither valid nor a contradiction. Invalid means not valid, that is contradictory or contingent.

Comment: These two meanings do converge, because an argument is a conditional proposition of the form <conjunction of premises>$\to$<conclusion>, and an argument being valid means that this conditional is valid (i.e., logically true).